# Need a way to dynamically sum multiple columns into a Merged cell of varying heights

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, split, vlookup, flatten

[image]

In this scenario, I am looking to total Columns G through M by 'user' in Column E.  Column N does have the correct data, but it is using the formula =sum(f4:m5).  I am looking for a way to add an array formula because the heights of the merged cells in column N varies often.  A formula would be preferred to a script in this case.

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(G2:M="",,F2:F&"♀"&G2:M)), "♀"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!  Thank you for your help!